# How to write xpath

Tags: xpath, automated-tests, robotframework

I want to get text `"+12345"` from this `HTML`

```
<p class="Test" ng-repeat="(k, wl) in partnerEditModel.td">
    <span id="Test-update-12345" class="ng-binding">
        +12345
        <span class="err-message ng-binding">Error</span>
    </span>
    <a id="mibile" class="button" ng-click="remove(k)">
</p>
```

I have written `"//p[@class='Test']/span` but it matched `"+12345Error"` which I have just wanted `"+12345"` (I have not wanted `"Error"`.)

Could you please tell me about how to write this `xpath`?

Comment: You need to say not only what the HTML is like, but what it _might_ be like. If you knew it was exactly like this, then you could hard code the answer. The key to writing a good XPath expression is to cope with variations in what the HTML might contain.

Answer (score 0):

Try below `XPath` expression to get `"+12345"` only:

```
normalize-space(//span[@id="Test-update-12345"]/text()[1])
```

Comment: I does not want to identify "+12345" in xpath

Comment: Ok. Then try `normalize-space(//p[@class='Test']/span/text()[1])`

Answer (score 0):

Try below code in robot framework

```
${var}= | Get Text | xpath=//span[span[@class='err-message ng-binding']]
Log | ${var}
```

Comment: I try to use //span[span[@class='err-message ng-binding']]/text() in RobotFramework but it has occurred error "either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:"

Comment: using this xpath with Get Value Function in Robot Framework

Comment: I hope you have added xpath=(then above xpath), though edited my answer now

Comment: I have already added xpath but it has occurred Error InvalidSelectorError: The result of the xpath expression //span[span[@class='err-message ng-binding']]/text() is: [object Text]. It should be an element.

Comment: I have edited my reply again. I hope you can achieve your scenario using Get Text keyword if you are working on robot framework

Answer (score -1):

Try using below:

```
 xpath=//p[@class='Test']/span[1]
```